# Multiple columns in List box control

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, multiple-columns

How can I display two columns in a list box?

Comment: Short answer...you can't, that's not how the control (at least the one in the framework) is designed, can you explain or illustrate a bit more what you're after?

Comment: @xrx215: If the only intention is to display the data column wise - meaning no user interaction - then you can add spaces to render data as columns; just thinking...!

Comment: Hi..

I need to display name and description columns coming from a web service.
these columns should be scrollable in the listbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A list box wasn't designed to display multi-column data. Even the Windows Forms version doesn't directly support that kind of data display.

Your requirements aren't clear, but the simplest way to go would be to use a [GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) control. It gives you a lot of functionality out of the box, and you can expand it to more columns very easily. If you need more control over the look or functionality, you can use a [DataList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) instead.

To get the scrolling ability, you can either use a scrolling `<div>` or simply use the pagination mechanism of the GridView if that's appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

You could line it up as if the data was in 2 columns

```
new ListItem("blah1".PadRight(10, ' ') + "blah2");
```

as shown here: http://articles.dotheweb.net/post/Formatting-columns-in-a-ListBox-of-ComboBox.aspx

Also, you could roll your own with a DataList.

Comment: Concatenating two separate columns of data into one is a bad idea for data integrity and would almost certainly require more code effort later on when you need to extract the selected value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use columns in a ListBox, you have to do it based on alignment.

For example:

```
String columns = "{0, -55}{1, -35}{2, -35}";
ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format(columns, "Filename", "Selected DateModified", "Vault DateModified"));
ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format(columns, fileName, datetime1, datetime2));
```

Output of my own implementation of this code below:

[image]

Keep in mind the font you use has to be a monospaced font, otherwise the alignment will mess up due to variable spacing between characters (and this exaggerates the longer the string is).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should write your own control, or you can use the listview control.

Answer (score 0):

As Nick Craver has already commented, the ListView probably isn't the right control for multi-column information.

Instead of hacking your list to appear as if it has two columns, it might be a better idea to use a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc5cbb9z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). It'll be easier to setup, format, and your data will be held in a much more flexible way.

DataGridViews also support [assigning Lists of objects as datasources](http://dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tips), if that makes things easier.

Answer (score 0):

use list view it is perfect alternative for multi column list box

Comment: This just repeats Haranadh's answer from 2 years prior. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2646553/2756409

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, you want a data column to display horizontal. This can be acheived by using a `DataList` and have `RepeatDirection` set to "Hozizontal" with the specified repeat columns. 
Eg :

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="5" CellSpacing="10" >
```

Answer (score -1):

Multiple items side by side are possible if you reference the toolkit and add the wrapPanelOrientation ;)
it will list look like

```
1stItem      2ndItem

3rdItem      4thItem .. ect..

ListBox.ItemsPanel>

ItemsPanelTemplate>
    toolkit:WrapPanelOrientation="Horizontal"FlowDirection="LeftToRight"ItemWidth="220"ItemHeight="60"/>

/ItemsPanelTemplate>

/ListBox.ItemsPanel>

/ListBox>
```